# 2D array to 3D plane

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, 2d, calculus

I am trying to create a 3D plane out of a collection of 2D points for a game I am making. I have omitted the Z axis in my illustration as the depth is constant. Also the plane will consist of multiple 3D models; one per line segment:

[image]

The original 2D points will form the top layer of the plane. I have successfully created the 3D plane v1, but as you can see from the illustration it leaves me with some issues with overlapping and cracks in the ground.

My problem is understanding how to properly calculate the positions for A1, ...., E1 while still keeping the thickness of the line constant.

Let me add that I have already available the signed angle of each line segment and also that a line segment can be on top of another forming a ceiling. This is however randomly generated.

Can someone please help point me in the direction of the calculations/algorithm that are needed to properly calculate this? I have been thinking of Pythagoras, but want to avoid the square root, hence I think the line angles can prove useful.

Comment: You can offset the lines AB, BC, CD and DE by a distanc equal to the thickness, then compute the intersection points between two consecutive offset lines to get the point B1, C1 and D1.

Comment: Using square roots is often faster than calculating angles via arc tangents; see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316995/which-is-more-efficient-atan2-or-sqrt) on a variation of your problem.